# Apache2 + wsgi + mysql not working but from Django it's working

Tags: mysql, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have updated my server and now I have a problem with my website under Django.

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
...

[Sat Jul 03 00:50:56.975729 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5009] [client 93.21.219.190:57598]   File "Django-2.1/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
[Sat Jul 03 00:50:56.975744 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5009] [client 93.21.219.190:57598]     import MySQLdb as Database
[Sat Jul 03 00:50:56.975766 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5009] [client 93.21.219.190:57598]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
[Sat Jul 03 00:50:56.975805 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5009] [client 93.21.219.190:57598]     version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
[Sat Jul 03 00:50:56.975850 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5009] [client 93.21.219.190:57598] NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

I have found some solutions but nothing works.

I have reinstalled mod_wsgi and mysqlclient :

```
pip3 install mod_wsgi
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

wsgi is linked to libpython3.8 and _mysql.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.sois linked to

```
ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff394b000)
    libpython3.8.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0 (0x00007f6a1fa15000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6a1f9f3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6a1f82e000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f6a1f7ff000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6a1f7e2000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f6a1f7a7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6a1f79f000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f6a1f79a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6a1f656000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6a1ffc9000)


ldd  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffccf18f000)
    libmysqlclient.so.21 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21 (0x00007efe00610000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007efe0044b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007efe00429000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007efe00423000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007efe00391000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007efe000a5000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007efe00089000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007efe0007e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007efdffeb1000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007efdffd6d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007efdffd53000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007efe00d2c000)

ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21

ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 juil.  2 23:19 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.8
```

**If I run my the django shell I can import mysqldb :**

```
python3 manage.py shell
import MySQLdb as Database
Here I can query the database with Model.objects.filter(...)
```

To conclude : from the django shell it's working, from apache2 it's not working. I don't understand what happen :/

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with a similar issue with Apache Airflow, running in a docker container.

adding `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` as an env var fixed this issue for me.